# Saved files go where and wi-fi problem

Tags: 12.04

1. I have two questions. Suppose I save a file or a video where does it go ? This is one of my question.

   2. I have a wi-fi connection. It works perfectly in my phone. In my laptop it worked for a few days. Then one day when I opened it wi-fi was not working but in my phone it was working. I must have done something in settings but I do not know how to rectify it. Kindly help me for this issue.

Comment: You have two very unrelated questions that will receive two unrelated answers.  It would benefit the community better (other people with similar questions) if you asked them in two different questions.  This way you can accept an answer that others could use.  Also when you start to type in a question, suggestions are presented that might resolve your issue before you type in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question one is usually the Downloads folder under the users home directory.

Answer to question two needs more  information to be answered such as what do you mean by not working. Do you see your network but cant log in? can you see networks but  not yours? Does it say no wireless networks found? Any error messages?  All relevant information would be helpful.

This may sound foolish but make sure your wireless is turned on on your laptop. I know that some laptops have a physical  switch that can turn off the wifi so first step would be to verify that it is on if you have a computer with a physical switch.

Answer (score 0):

**Saving files on Ubuntu**

You have a home folder that you can see by clicking on your files browser (it looks like a file cabinet in the Launcher.

If you bring it up and click on home you'll see all the files that are saved in your home directory.

Some applications might save a file to a specific area by file type.  You can click on special folders such as **`Documents`**, **`Pictures`**,**`Downloads`**, **Music**, **`Videos`** and **`Desktop`** to see if one of your applications has saved a file to one of those particular areas.

If you are not sure and want to specify an area you can click on `Save as` from the application, then browse and pick the area of your choice.

**Program Configuration files**

Many applications will save configuration files to remember specific settings and preferences.  These files will be saved in areas such as:

- a folder by the name of the program
- a folder prefixed by a dot (such as `.thunderbird`)
- a sub folder of `.local/share`

**Recent Files**

Often you can find a file by clicking on `Recent` in your file browser.  You'll see recent files that have been saved.  You can right click on the desired file and click on `Open Location` to see where it is saved.

**The Launch Button**

Ubuntu's Lauch search button will also show you recent saved files.  A right click on a desired file there will also give you the option of opening the folder (`Open Location`) where it's saved.